# Check TLS1.2 for SQL Server Connection

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to check if the connection between my application and SQL Server is used TLS1.2.
I disabled TLS1.2 but the connection still happened. I checked via wireshark and saw nothing about TLS1.2.

Answer (score 0):

Please tell us whether your SQL Server is 2012 as the tag displayed. If so, firstly, please check whether the patch for enabling TLS 1.2 is installed.

Next please check whether the update for client components and drivers are installed.

Please refer to the article: [TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server).

SQL Server in Windows also supports TLS1.0 and TLS1.1. If you want to use only TLS 1.2 for client-server communication, please disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1.

Please try to disable TLS1.0 1.1 and 1.2, then reboot your machine and test whether the connection can do well.

By the way, you can see the blog to [verify if a connection to SQL Server is Encrypted](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sqlman/2009/01/26/verifying-if-a-connection-to-sql-server-is-encrypted/).